# Java Conditional operator three possible results

Tags: java, conditional-operator

How to break the conditional code you can see below into a regular `if`-statement to understand how it works, since it has three results.

I changed values just to see where its going:

```
System.out.print(("A"=="A")?("B"=="B")?"1":"2":"3");


 /*
 if A is False (Output = 3)
 if B is False (Output = 2)
 if A&B are True (Output = 1)
 */
```

Comment: Shouldn't A and B be of type boolean?

Comment: What is the output you’re getting with above sys out.

Comment: Can I offer you some more parentheses?  Is it easier to understand if you put a `(` just after the first `?` and a `)` just before the last `:` perhaps?

Comment: the output is 1 since both are true

Comment: [Java String constant pool](https://study.com/academy/lesson/java-string-constant-pool-concept-mechanism.html) so if pool is not off `"A" == "A"` and `"B" == "B"` will be true because java.lang.String references are same, and expression will be resolved to true, as well as print `1`.

Comment: Are you using == to compare strings on purpose? You know that doing so is a really bad idea?

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem Probably the whole point here is to force pupils to carefully look at the code. Intentionally strange code, meant to make people think. Or delegate the heavy thinking to other people ...

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem same results but it cleared it a bit more for me , is  `B` condition not in the same level as `A` condition is `B` inside `A` condition block ? if its then its so confusing how java knew it was meant to be like this without the `(`

Comment: @GhostCat i pasted the code like this because i got a question i need to answer same as this code and there is no compile error thats why i needed to understand it

Comment: Well, there are plenty of questions here and nicely written explanations elsewhere that perfectly explain you what a ternary operator is, and how it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The conditional (ternary) operator works in the following manner:

> (predicate) ? (onTrueValue) : (onFalseValue);

so in your case what we have is :

```
("A"=="A" ? ("B"=="B" ? "1" : "2") : "3");
```

Which evals to:

```
Is A equal to A? 
If yes -> return Is B equal to B
    If yes -> return 1;
    If no -> return 2;
If no -> return 3;
```

Similar to:

```
condition1 ? (condition2 ? val1 : val2) : val3;
```

And some tests for verification

```
// Prints 1 as both conditions are true.
System.out.println("A"=="A" ? ("B"=="B" ? "1" : "2") : "3");
// Prints 3 as first condition fails.
System.out.println("A"=="notA" ? ("B"=="B" ? "1" : "2") : "3");
// Prints 2 as second condition fails.
System.out.println("A"=="A" ? ("B"=="notB" ? "1" : "2") : "3");
```

Also note that your are uising the `==` operator for comparing strings. In this particular case this will give no difference just use it with caution...

Answer (score 2):

Your code can be split like this:

```java
String message;
if ("A" == "A") {
    if ("B" == "B") {
        message = "1";
    } else {
        message = "2";
    }
} else {
    message = "3";
}
System.out.print(message);
```

A ternary operator works like an `if`-statement that returns a value. However it can only be places where an expression could stand, so it cannot stand on it's own.
The part before the `?` is the condition, the one after is the then expression. Behind the `:` is the else expression.
Nested ternary `?:` operators are very bad to read, and should definetly be avoided.

Comment: thanks alot this answered my question i asked this because i had the same exact code in a question i had that i needed to understand before answering it.

Comment: Correct. Fixed it. It's 'ternary'.

Answer (score 1):

If i understand you correctly and A, B, and C are booleans, this might be what you want:

```
System.out.print( ((!A)? "3" : (!B)? "2" : "1"));
```

For Strings you'd have to make sure to use A.equals(B).